# How to extend / override the JFile class?

Tags: joomla-3.x, file-upload, class-extensions

I want to extend/override the `JFile` class without hacking Joomla files.  How do I even begin to extend the class using best practices?

Comment: JFile is not a view which you can simply override in Joomla, rather it is a core framework concept. What changes want to make in that?

Comment: You will not be able to do so without making the changes in core, if you need some functionality for your own extension you can extend the JFile class to do your own task by overriding the methods.
Please provide some more information as to what you want to achieve.